# ruby 2.1 rails 4 and ZenTest 4.9.5 - multigem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zentest

I'm setting up a new computer and trying to bundle install a project -- I'm getting:

```
ZenTest's executable "multigem" conflicts with /Users/grimm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/multigem
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  n
ERROR:  Error installing ZenTest:
"multigem" from ZenTest conflicts with /Users/grimm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/multigem
```

I'm PROBABLY going to flip to Ruby2.0 for this but curious why no one else is getting this error?

Comment: Have you tried overwriting the executable and seeing what happens?

Comment: issue `find /Users/grimm/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/ -name multigem`